# Spring JPA with OSGI

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data

I am trying `Spring(4.5) data JPA` with `OSGI` and using the java based spring configuration but facing issues for scanning the spring components/packages.
I have tried the below options to share the same class loader for my project and spring bundles using

1. Buddy policy
2. Fragments

but still facing the same issue. I would appreciate the help in this case. See the below **error** which I am getting:

> o.s.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver
>   Cannot search for matching files underneath URL
>   [bundleresource://261.fwk57497692/com/misys/fbp/frameworkInformation/dao/]
>   because it does not correspond to a directory in the file system
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: URL
>   [bundleresource://261.fwk57497692/com/misys/fbp/frameworkInformation/dao/]
>   cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in
>   the file system:
>   bundleresource://261.fwk57497692/com/misys/fbp/frameworkInformation/dao/
>                       at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:212)
>                       at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractFileResolvingResource.getFile(AbstractFileResolvingResource.java:52)
>                       at org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource.getFile(UrlResource.java:212)
>                       at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.doFindPathMatchingFileResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:598)
>                       at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.findPathMatchingResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:419)

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="osgibundle:com.misys.fbp.frameworkInformation.repository")
@ComponentScan(basePackages="osgibundle:com.misys.fbp.frameworkInformation.dao")
public class PersistenceJPAConfig{

   @Bean
   public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
      LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
      em.setDataSource(dataSource());
      em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "osgibundle:com.misys.fbp.frameworkInformation.model"});

      JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
      em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
      em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

      return em;
   }
```

Comment: Can you post your Spring and JPA configuration?

Comment: Possible a duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16795205/spring-component-scan-broken-in-osgi-container

Comment: That may not solve my issue as I use java based configuration not xml based so even if I create bean for my service how the CrudRepository will be injected in as it is implemeted on the fly by Spring.

Comment: Do we have any working Spring JPA code working in OSGI with java based configuration?